# Не добавляется манифест в jar из командной строки

Tags: java, jar

День добрый! Из командной строки запускаю след. команду:

```
jar cvfm classes.jar mymanifest build/mypackage/MyClass.class
```

и в результате в jar манифест не попадает, а создается системой автоматически, где Main-Class не указан, mymanifest лежит в той-же папке откуда запускаю командную строку. Что я не так делаю?

Comment: `mymanifest` покажите. Возможно нет перевода строки после `Main-Class: whatever`, он обязателен.

Comment: да, спасибо! после добавления перевода строки манифест стал добавляться. Теперь другая проблема: при попытке указать директорию с class-файлами через -C: -C build\ просто вываливает usage и все, пробовал и build и build/ все одно и тоже. Система: Windows 7 x64